# How can I bind onchange event on dynamically created input ? (no jquery)

Tags: javascript, events, listener

I'm using a function that dynamically inject inputs .
I want to be able to listen to these inputs changes.

Here is what I currently have :

```
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.setAttribute('value', '');
input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
input.setAttribute('class', 'my-custom-input');
document.body.appendChild(input);
```

And here is what I'm trying to do : (without jquery)

```
$(document).on('change', '.my-custom-input', function(){
                  // do something
})
```

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following:

```js
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.setAttribute('value', '');
input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
input.setAttribute('class', 'my-custom-input');
document.body.appendChild(input);

//Change event listener
input.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  console.log('I just changed');
}, false);
```